# pig script to sum all rows without doing group by on any single column

Tags: group-by, apache-pig

I need it without doing group by on any particular field. My input data is,

(a,3)

(b,1)

(c,4)

(d,6)

(e,7)

How do i sum up all the numbers without using group by function? Expected result is,

(5,21).

It would be helpful if you show it how.

Comment: You could find the answer in short order if you simply plug the title of the question into Google.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#GROUP).  You want to `GROUP ALL` rather than `GROUP BY`.